# How to use embedBuilder in zefyr?

Tags: flutter, editor, flutter-dependencies

How to use embedBuilder in zefyr 1.0.0-dev.2.0? I want to add images using image picker and display them on Zefyr Editor? How do I achieve this?

Comment: Having the same problem - did you figure it out? Could you share an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the example code provided in this GitHub issue comment: https://github.com/memspace/zefyr/issues/421#issuecomment-708202346

Comment: Followed it but got `You must pass your own builder function to embedBuilder property of ZefyrEditor or ZefyrField widgets` - could you share how to make it?